# Python Text game Job

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a python game and I want a working system. So I made a function!

```
def player_job_get(job_list, player_job, player_level):
    print('Available jobs :')
    for i,job in enumerate(job_list, 1):
        print(i, job)
    job_chose = input('What job number do you want? ("q" to exit)')
    if job_chose == 'q':
        return player_job

    try:
        job_chose = int(job_chose)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please use the number next to the job')
        return player_job

    if job_chose <= len(job_list):
        if player_job == None:
            print('Sucessfully got the job!')
            player_job = ???
            return player_job
        else:
            print('You already have a job!')
            retire = input('Would you like to retire from your current job?  y/n\n')
            if retire == 'y':
                player_job = None
                player_job = ???
                return player_job
            elif retire == 'n':
                print('Sorry you can only have 1 job at a time!')
                return player_job
            else:
                print('y or n please!')
                return player_job
```

The function above is if the player wants a new job. In the main game function, I put

```
elif chat == '!gj':
    player_job = player_job_get(job_list, player_job, player_level)
```

But the problem is I don't know what to put in the

```
???
```

in the line

```
player_job = ???
```

In the player_job_get function

What should I replace the ??? with? When I run the command it looks like this (by the way when I ran the function It would say the ??? is an error so I changed the ??? into 'job' for now

[image: Get job run example]

It would say that I sucessfully got the job but my job would be 'job'.

Comment: Why do you need that line? What's wrong with `player_job = None`?

Comment: As a picky stylistic point, I would take all of the `return player_job` lines out of your big `if` statement, to just let them flow through, and add `return player_job` as the last line of the function.  It's a general but vague rule that early exits make code harder to understand.